# Displaying certain items on a ComboBox

Tags: .net, vb.net, combobox

I got a problem where I need to show specific calibration gases that are in current use, but I need to keep the expired gases for historical reasons. There are over 100 records in our database, so it's a long list!

The list is being populated from a SQL Server 2008:

```
SELECT CalGasID, GasConc, GasContent, GasSerialNo, InUse FROM CalibrationGases
```

And I store the data into this class (in VB.Net 2008):

```
  Public Class GasInfo
    Private _gasID As String
    Private _Conc As String
    Private _serial As String
    Private _inUse As Boolean

    Public Property GasID() As String
        Get
            Return Me._gasID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._gasID = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Concentration() As String
        Get
            Return Me._Conc
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._Conc = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Serial() As String
        Get
            Return Me._serial
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._serial = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property InUse() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me._inUse
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            Me._inUse = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Public Sub New()
        Me._gasID = String.Empty
        Me._Conc = String.Empty
        Me._serial = String.Empty
        Me._inUse = False
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal gasID, ByVal conc, ByVal id, ByVal inUse)
        Me._gasID = gasID
        Me._Conc = conc
        Me._serial = id
        Me._inUse = inUse
    End Sub

End Class
```

And the ComboBox:

```
    Private _gasConcList As New List(Of GasInfo)

    Me.ComboBoxGas1.DataSource = _gasConcList
    Me.ComboBoxGas1.DisplayMember = "Concentration"
    Me.ComboBoxGas1.ValueMember = "GasID"
    Me.ComboBoxGas1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
```

So what I want is when the InUse is set to TRUE, I want it to be shown in the dropdown list, but I need also to show the the text of the last gas calibration, if it is already there, to be displayed even if it expired (InUse set to FALSE).

My alternative is only make a master list of what gases are currently active, and then when it comes to that record, add the old calibration gas as the first item, and then append the "InUse" master list.

But does someone else have a better way or method where I can do it with just one list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Me.ComboxBoxGas1.DataSource = _gasConcList.Where(Function(x) x.InUse = True OrElse x.GasID = selectedGasID).ToList()
```

where `selectedGasID` is the last gas calibration value.

Comment: Genius! That worked fine! I was a bit worried that I might need to use Sub instead of Function since I'm working with VS 2008. I wish that this company would upgrade to 2013